# What is the literary device for "our eyes opened" when describing a realization?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning, literary-device

This is a quote from the book *Night*, by Elie Wiesel. In context: "We realized that we were not staying in Hungary. Our eyes opened. Too late."

Answer (score 1):

To *open one's eyes* is an idiom:

> to begin to notice or be aware of something important. *You need to open your eyes and face the truth.*

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/open%20one%27s%20eyes)

The next step: to open one's eyes *to something* is *to realize something.*

Answer (score 0):

A *figurative* use of **eye open**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/131699#eid115726041)

> with eyes (wide) open and ... variants: fully aware of the risks and other
>   implications of an action or situation.

As in:

> "Our eyes opened (became aware of the implications). Too late."